# How to replace a parent batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I've got an **applicationStart.bat** file that calls this **update.bat**, and I need the update.bat to replace the applicationStart.bat with a new one.

The code of the **applicationStart.bat** is something like:

```
@echo off

call update.bat

java -Xms128m -Xmx256m com.foo.bar
```

And the code of the **update.bat** is like:

```
@echo off

..\JRE\bin\jar.exe -xvf .\updateFile.jar
```

I've already tried putting the applicationStart.bat inside de updateFile.jar, and on some machines it replace without error, but on other machines it will generate an error and abort the extraction.

The applicationStart.bat just remains being used for the rest of the day, when the application is being used, and in some cases, the user can shutdown the machine from the application, making things harder because I can't create another process to wait for the application to end and replace the applicationStart.bat afterwards.

How can I get this **applicationStart.bat** to be replaced?

Comment: What error(s) are being generated?

Comment: @Magoo the error is that the file I'm trying to replace is still in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just've managed to do it without editing the applicationStart.bat!

To achieve that I've created a 3rd batch called **batkill.bat**:

```
@echo off

if exist temp\applicationStart.bat (
    title batkill
    taskkill /IM cmd.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne batkill" /F
    taskkill /IM ping.exe /F
    move /Y temp\applicationStart.bat .
    start applicationStart.bat
    exit
)
```

And I just've ajusted the **update.bat** to:

```
@echo off

rem Still need to do this to keep the other updates the application needs, 
rem without the applicationStart.bat inside
..\JRE\bin\jar.exe -xvf .\updateFile.jar

if exist temp\applicationStart.bat (
    start batkill.bat
    rem Waiting 10 seconds while the batkill comes to kills me
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 -w 1000 >nul
)
```

This way the applicationStart.bat remains unchanged while in execution and I need to change only the update.bat (which is easy to change and deploy)

Answer (score 0):

Applicationstart.bat:

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="::" goto mainline
update.bat

:mainline
java -Xms128m -Xmx256m com.foo.bar
```

update.bat

```
@echo off
..\JRE\bin\jar.exe -xvf .\updateFile.jar
applicationstart.bat ::
```

`::` is a longtime-used parameter-value for varying the behaviour of a batch file.

Another approach to Applicationstart.bat:

```
@echo off
%1 update.bat

java -Xms128m -Xmx256m com.foo.bar
```

In this version, applicationstart.bat will substitute *nothing* for `%1` hence execute `update` but when replaced and re-invoked will have `::` (or `rem`) substituted for `%1` and hence no run `update.bat`

Comment: Is there any way I could do this without editing the applicationStart.bat? I ask that because I already have this batch in over 4000 computers, and I can't just edit it to alter the update.bat call

Comment: I've thought about creating a 3rd batch file, and starting it in another process... the 3rd one would kill the first process, replace the applicationStart.bat, and then call it again

Comment: Fair enough - but aren't you updating applicationStart.bat from update.bat anyway?